# when i put 3 if statements prints all of them

Tags: python

The following uses variables I have not shown the initialization of, but you can make up your own.  It does exactly what I want it to do but it prints all of the if's not just 1 one the if's.

```
m = input()
if m == 1:
    print(l)
    time.sleep(1)
else:
    print(cost + f + baws)
    boss_he = boss_he - 20
    print("%" + str(boss_he) + " boss health left")

if m == 2:
    time.sleep(1)
else:
    print(cost + baws)
    boss_he = boss_he - 25
    print('%' + str(boss_he) + ' boss health left')
if m == 3:
    time.sleep(1)
else:
    print(h)
    wiz_he = wiz_he + 15
    print('%' + str(wiz_he) + " of you health left")
```

Whenever I run this code it will execute every else case, why?

If each else prints a 1, or a 1, or a 3 if I put that number, it will print 1 2 and 3 instead if just printing 1(if i asked it to print 1). Is it something wrong with my code?

Comment: if m is not in 1, 2, or 3 then you will hit all three elses.

Comment: The point of asking for more details is for you to provide details (such as the steps you've taken to try to solve the issue), not to create some arbitrary hurdle. Anyway, try fixing your `if..else` structure (by adding `elif` where necessary) and then turning `m` into an `int` with `m = int(input())`.

Comment: `Is it something wrong with my code?` Well, yes, because it doesn't work the way you want it to.

Comment: ok, so how do i fix the code? It is like no help if you just say yes , can you explain how to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

Your `input()` will **never** evaluate to any of your `if` statmenet,s because you are taking `input()` as a `str`. Thus, all the `else`s are triggered. Instead, cast `int`: `m = int(input())`. Also, your logic is flawed, because if `m` is not `1`, `2`, or `3`, all the `else` statements will be entered.

Comment: That is if the OP uses Python 3 as in Python 2 `input()` is an integer

Comment: Oh, his logic is flawed, is it, Mr. Vulcan? (I agree.)

Comment: so how can i fix it then,  because the op is going to use 1, 2, or 3 also i am using python 3, is that a problem?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use if,elif,elif and else instead of using if several times? And the program determines your input as string so that make it like m=int(input()) to convert your input to an integer